'density' of the integral curve of a vector field
Electric field lines are essentially the integral curve of a vector field in the language of differential geometry, in the sense that they are the image of the mapping. However, the density of the electric field lines is proportional to the field strength. 'Density' at a given point refers to the number of field lines pass through a surface element perpendicular to them.
In mathematics, do the density of integral curves at a given point proportional to the magnitude of the vector?
If the answer is no, where does this property/rule come from?

"the image of the mapping"? Of course, there are infinitely many field lines passing through a surface element. What precisely are we seeing in the picture?

@ Ted Shifrin I am a physics student. As I understand it, the curves in differential geometry mean two separate things. 1. the mapping from a interval on R to manifold 2. the image on the manifold, or the meaning of 'curve' in everyday language. In physics, becuase we don't assign parameters on electric field lines most of the time and field line is more close to the second meaning I mentioned. That's why I said 'the image of the mapping'.

@ Ted Shirfrin This is the physics question I posted which provide a specific context  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/833771/why-is-electric-field-strength-indicated-by-the-density-of-field-lines
